# Почему не корректно подсвечивается синтаксис кода в Python в VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

1. Нет подсветки всех функций, например writer, writerow.
2. Почему функции def,  with, open, zip, разного цвета?

Код Python:

[image]

Установленные расширения:

[image]

В Pycharm подсветка работает нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Включил в VSCode тему Темная+ (темная по умолчанию), не верная подсветка осталась, я думаю это проблема в самом VSCode.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удалил все расширение, в том числе "Python", VSCodium подсветку не изменил, все как было осталось, походу VSCodium не понимает, что работает с python кодом.

Comment: А почему они должны быть одинаковы? Это семантически разные элементы - и разная подсветка само собой.

Comment: with оператор, все остальное функции

Comment: Хорошо, с разным типом подсветки разобрались. Почему другие две функции не подсвечивает: writer, writerow ?

Comment: Все еще может от используемой цветовой схемы зависеть. У вас выглядит как цветовая схема Sublime Text, вот так выглядит в цветовой схеме Dark+ (default dark): https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q9SL.png

Comment: Включил в VSCode тему Темная (+ темная по умолчанию), не верная подсветка осталась, я думаю это проблема в самом VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсветка зависит от используемого языкового движка (Language Server, настройка `python.languageServer`). Со стандартным Jedi подсветка выглядит так (цветовая схема Dark+):

[image: jedi]

C Pylance (требуется установка соответствующего расширения) подсветка выглядит так:

[image: pylance]

Comment: Спасибо большое, сделал как вы сказали и все получилось.